# Getting sum grouped by different fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my table

```
 PayerID PaymentID Amount

    1   8386    5827.14
    1   8386    5827.14
    1   8386    5827.14
    1   8387    4464.68
    1   8387    4464.68
    1   8387    4464.68
    2   8388    1482.57
    2   8388    1482.57
    2   8388    1482.57
    2   8388    1482.57
    2   8388    1482.57
    2   8388    1482.57
    2   8388    1482.57
    2   8388    1482.57
    2   8388    1482.57
```

I want Sum of Amount for distinct PaymentID group by PayerID like below

```
payerID AmountSum
1        5827.14 + 4464.68
2         1482.57
```

Comment: `SELECT SUM(distinct amount) FROM table GROUP BY payerID`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SUM(DISTINCT)`

```
SELECT PayerId, SUM(DISTINCT Amount) AS AmountSum
FROM tab
GROUP BY PayerId;
```

This solution assumes that `Amount` is unique for different `PaymentId`.

---

More general approach:

```
SELECT PayerId, SUM(Amount) AS AmountSum
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PayerID, PaymentID, Amount
      FROM tab) sub
GROUP BY PayerId
```

Comment: Some times Amount is same and Payment ID will be different. like 8386 and 8387 can have amount as 5827.14 so it should be based on PaymentID

Answer (score 0):

You can query using row_number as below:

```
Select PayerId, sum(amount) from (
    Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by Payerid, PaymentId, Amount order by Amount) from #payerdata
) a
where a.RowN = 1
group by PayerId
```

Output as below:

```
+---------+-----------+
| PayerId | AmountSum |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |  10291.82 |
|       2 |   1482.57 |
+---------+-----------+
```